# Why MYSQL returns different result for a+2=b+1=c vs a+1 = b and b+1=c?

Tags: mysql

I write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively:

| ***Id*** | ***Num***|

| 1   |   1  |

| 2   |   1  |

| 3   |   1  |

| 4   |   2  |

| 5   |   1  |

| 6   |   2  |

| 7   |   2  |

For example, given the above ***Logs*** table, ***1*** is the only number that appears consecutively for at least three times.

My original query returns 1 and 2:

```
 SELECT l1.Num
    FROM Logs l1, Logs l2, Logs l3
    WHERE l1.Id + 2 = l2.Id + 1 = l3.Id
    AND l1.Num = l2.Num = l3.Num;
```

+------------------------------------------------------------------------

Then I change my query to this (basically I change the a+2 = b+1 = c to a + 1 = b and b+1 = c), it returns the correct answer:

```
SELECT l1.Num
FROM Logs l1, Logs l2, Logs l3
WHERE l1.Id + 1 = l2.Id AND l2.Id + 1 = l3.Id
AND l1.Num = l2.Num AND l1.Num= l3.Num;
```

+------------------------------------------------------------------------

It drives me crazy, I cannot figure our why. Could anyone kindly explain this to me? Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: In SQL `=` is the same as `==` in many other laguages.

Comment: `2 = 2 = 2` => `(2 = 2) = 2` => `(1) = 2` => `0` (FALSE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's have a look at this query:

`WHERE l1.Id + 2 = l2.Id + 1 = l3.Id`

In MySQL as in most programming languages, the `=` is just a binary operator, which means it takes a left and a right side and returns true if they are the same and false if otherwise.

In your query, you're first comparing `l1.Id + 1` with `l2.Id` resulting in a truth value. And then, you compare the truth value with `l3.Id`. (The truth value gets automatically casted to `0`/`1`). This leads to a different result.

tl;dr: `=` in MySQL is not like `=` often used in mathematical notation.

Comment: "In MySQL as in most programming languages" - in most programming languages i know `==` is used. Besides SQL is not a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple `=` operators (i.e. chaining), MySQL evaluates it from left to right, result of left most comparison is then fed to next operation. Have a look at this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9ecb0/1/0)**:

`id=id=2` returns false because `id=id` returns 1 and `1 != 2`.

Now, as far as query is concerned, I believe there is a simpler way to do it, using variables in `SELECT`. Based on your approach, if we were to find all the numbers that occur 4 times then we need to do another join. Instead, we can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, num, 
@counter := IF(@previousNum = num, @Counter + 1, 1) AS counter,
@previousNum := num as prevNum
FROM test, (select @counter := 1, @previousNum := -1) a
ORDER BY id;
```

This returns id and values along with counter that is incremented if consecutive ids have same `num` value.

Now, if we want to filter out the values with more than 3 appearances, we need to wrap this query in another select statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT id 
FROM
(SELECT id, num, 
    @counter := IF(@previousNum = num, @Counter + 1, 1) AS counter,
    @previousNum := num as prevNum
    FROM test, (select @counter := 1, @previousNum := -1) a
    ORDER BY id) a
WHERE a.counter >= 3;
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1eca1/13/0)**. You can easily change the counter value to find out values for different number of consecutive appeareances.